# Rails save not working on gem cocoon with different edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem, cocoonjs

Friends , I have a model order that has many details. I am using the cocoon gem to generate forms . They render ok but are not saving . I click the button to save and nothing happens ,  and rails console shows nothing. The default edit form, called detail_fields saves with no problem. But i had to create this one called detail_fields_dev,  and this one is not working. Can someone help?

routes.rb

```
resources :details
resources :orders
get '/orders/:id/devolucao' => 'orders#devolucao' , as: 'devolucao_order'
put '/orders/:id' => 'orders#update'
patch '/orders/:id' => 'orders#update'
```

orders_controller, is ok,  using the default rails code. I created this action to call the detail_fields_dev form:

```
def devolucao
# @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end
```

The details params are ok too:

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :valor_total,   :valor_total_dev, :item_total, :item_total_dev,:tipo,:descontado,:order_num, details_attributes: [:id,:order_id, :cod_produto, :desc_produto, :cod_cor, :desc_cor, :desc_tamanho,:preco,:quantidade,:quantidade_dev,:total, :total_dev,:barcode, :_destroy])
end
```

Order view:

_form_devolucao.html.erb

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-inputs form_fixed">
      <%= f.input :customer, :as => :hidden %>
      <%= f.input :tipo, :as => :hidden %>
      <%= f.input :descontado, :as => :hidden %>
      <%= f.input :valor_total, :as => :hidden %>
      <%= f.input :item_total, :as => :hidden %>
      <%= f.input :order_num, :as => :hidden %>
      <div class="row">
          <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns leitor_dev">
                      Código de barras
                      (<a href="http://zxing.appspot.com/scan?ret=http://www.auere.com.br/testes/barcode.php?codigo={CODE}">Leitor</a>):
                      <input class = "cod_barras_dev" type="text" name="cod_barras_dev" value="" />
          </div>
          </form>
        <div class="small-5 columns end not_found">
          <span class="not_found">Produto não existe neste pedido!</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">
            <hr/>
                <div id="details">
                  <%= f.simple_fields_for :details do |detail| %>
                       <%= render partial: "orders/detail_fields_dev", locals: {f: detail} %>
                     <% end %>
                </div>
      <hr/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="form-actions container">
          <%= link_to_add_association '+ ítens', f, :details, data: {"association-insertion-method" => :before, "association-insertion-node" => ".container  " },:class => "button tiny radius add" %>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-6 medium-2 columns">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Salvar" %>
      </div>
      <div class="small-6 medium-2 columns end">
        <%= link_to 'Cancelar', orders_path, :class => "button alert"%>

      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

And the partial orders/detail_fields_dev.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <div class="row listCod" data-cod="<%= f.object.barcode %>">
    <div class="small-6 columns show-for-small-only">
      <%= f.input :barcode, label: "Cod Barras", input_html: { class: 'barcode_ror_dev' } %>
    </div>
      <%= f.input :order_id, :as => :hidden, input_html: { class: 'order_id_ror_dev' } %>
      <div class="show-for-medium-up small-2 columns">
        <%= f.input :cod_produto, label: "Produto", input_html: { class: 'cod_produto_ror_dev' } %>
      </div>
      <%= f.input :desc_produto,:as => :hidden, input_html: { class: 'desc_produto_ror_dev' } %>
      <%= f.input :cod_cor,:as => :hidden, input_html: { class: 'cod_cor_ror_dev' } %>
      <div class="small-2 show-for-medium-up columns">
        <%= f.input :desc_cor,label: "Cor", input_html: { class: 'desc_cor_ror_dev' } %>
      </div>
      <div class="small-2 show-for-medium-up columns">
          <%= f.input :desc_tamanho,label: "Tam", input_html: { class: 'desc_tamanho_ror_dev' } %>
      </div>
      <div class="small-2 show-for-medium-up columns">
          <%= f.input :preco,label: "Preço",input_html: { class: 'preco_ror_dev' } %>
      </div>
      <div class="small-6 medium-2 columns">
          <%= f.input :quantidade_dev,label: "Qtd Dev", input_html: { class: 'quantidade_ror_dev' } %>
      </div>
      <div class="show-for-medium-up medium-2 columns end">
          <%= f.input :total_dev,label: "Total Dev",input_html: { class: 'total_ror_dev' } %>
      </div>
      <div class="small-1 columns end">
        <%= link_to_remove_association "-", f, :class => "button tiny alert remove"%>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output:

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkMDw.jpg)

Comment: Is there a javascript error when you click on the Save button ?

Comment: No. No js error. I used the same form as the one that is working only hidding some fields and changing some js behavior.

Comment: Is your controller receiving the params?

Comment: How can i double check thia?

Comment: Probably silly, but is the save button actually in the form? (your code is too messy for me to quickly see), but it would explain why clicking it would have no effect (e.g. not posting something to the controller).

Comment: Yes The save buttons are inside the form tag. As I said it is not being called. Its dead